# stderr /usr/local/bin/bundle: argument list too long while bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger, ansible

I am using ansible to do deployment for my rails app. The problem is when a new gem is added and the ansible runs `bundle install`, it gives the following error:

```
stderr /usr/local/bin/bundle: argument list too long
/usr/local/bin/bundle: line 7: /usr/local/bin/bundle: success
```

The ansible task to do bundle install is

```
- name: Bundle install
  command: 'bundle install --deployment --without development test'
  register: bundler
  args:
    chdir: '/home/ubuntu/myproject'
```

I am using rvm to manage ruby version. Using ruby-2.2.1 and I have set rvm to use gemset of myproject i.e. `rvm use ruby-2.2.1@myproject`.

The `.rvm/gems/` directory have `ruby-2.2.1/`              `ruby-2.2.1@global/`       `ruby-2.2.1@myproject/`

I have specified `passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.1@myproject/ruby`

This happens only when new gem is added in Gemfile, when there is only code update, everything works fine. If I run `bundle install` explicitly doing ssh to corresponding instance, it works fine and install the gem.
Any help and suggestion on this?

Comment: I don't know much about Ansible but just form the error message I presume that it is not picking up your rvm-version bundler but a system one (in `/usr/local`). Perhaps this might be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the issue. The problem was related to the path of bundle being used by the script was `/usr/local/bin/bundle` but it should be from `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myproject/bin/bundle`

The correct task of ansible is

```
- name: Bundle install
  command: bundle install --without development test
  args:
    chdir: /home/ubuntu/myproject
    executable: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myproject/bin/bundle
  environment:
    GEM_HOME:  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myproject
    GEM_PATH:  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myproject:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
```